# How to get physical keyboard layout in android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, ime

I'm working an Android app and want to get physical keyboard layout in settings. But I didn't find any way to get this information. I have checked all the constants in **Settings.Global**, **Settings.Secure**, **Settings.System**. There are `DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD` and `SELECTED_INPUT_METHOD_SUBTYPE`. But both of them are for software keyboard not physical keyboard. Is there any method to get physical keyboard settings?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such option Officially by Google but yes you can install physical keyboard layouts, some of them are as follows :

- [RS HARDWARE KEYBOARD LAYOUTS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tiagofalcao.raidsixinputdevices&hl=en)
- [External keyboard helper demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo)

Comment: Thanks for answering. So there is no way to get physical keyboard setting programmably? That's odd. Almost all other settings could be got, such as language, wifi, radio... Why only physical keyboard preference can't be got?

Comment: Till I know...Its  not..And I cant say why google hasn't provided this.This is mistery